# JQuery event after element refresh not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

After submitting forms Im doing an AJAX request, after success it "refreshes" a `<div>` with `.load()` function. The problem is that this element also contains forms, which have to do the same AJAX action. I could bind `'submit'` event onto all forms (also the loaded ones). But the problem is that with the event binded, after the element is refreshed and form is submitted, nothing happens. The forms, that were not refreshed are working fine

JQuery:

```
function formHandler(form) {    //Function, that is getting executed on form submit
    var req_url = form.attr('action') ? form.attr('action') : window.location.href;
    var req_method = form.attr('method') ? form.attr('method').toUpperCase() : 'GET';
    var req_data = new FormData(form[0]);
    req_data.append('token', getCookie('token'));
    $.ajax({    //Doing AJAX request onto PHP script
        type: req_method,
        url: req_url,
        data: req_data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function(msg) {    //On success, getting response and parsing it
            var parsed = JSON.parse(msg);
            switch (parsed.error) {
                case 0:
                    var element = '';    //Element that should be updated with .load()
                    if (req_data.get('coupon') != null ||
                        req_data.get('delcoup') != null ||
                        req_data.get('coupval') != null) {
                        element = '#changecpn';
                    } else if (req_data.get('sellfile') != null || req_data.get('newcname') != null ||
                        req_data.get('delitem') != null) {
                        element = '#changeitem';
                    } else if (req_data.get('news') != null ||
                        req_data.get('delnews') != null ||
                        req_data.get('newsval') != null) {
                        element = '#changenews';
                    } else {
                        element = '';
                    }
                    form[0].reset();    //Reset form fields
                    $(element).load(window.location.href + ' ' + element, function() {    //Load the same element from the same page, but with up[dated content
                        $(this).children().unwrap();   //Remove duplicate ID
                    });
                    break;
                case 1:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {   //On page load
    $(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {   //Bind 'submit' event to all forms
        e.preventDefault();
        formHandler($(this));   //Execute form handler
    });
});
```

Example of HTML Element:

```
<fieldset id="coupons">
   <legend>Coupons</legend>
   <br>
   <h4 class="zusatz">Add</h4>
   <form action="panelfuncs.php" method="post">   <!-- First form, that won't be updated -->
      <table style="width: 100%;">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td style="text-align: center;"><label for="coupon">Coupon</label></td>
               <td style="width: 40px;"><input type="text" name="coupon" id="coupon" placeholder="Coupon" maxlength="12" required=""></td>
               <td><input type="button" name="gen" id="gen" value="Generate" onclick="randomStr(12)"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td style="text-align: center;"><label for="drop">Decrease %</label></td>
               <td><input type="number" name="drop" id="drop" placeholder="Value" min="1" max="50" required=""></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <br>
      <table>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td><input type="submit" value="Add"></td>
               <td><input type="reset" value="Reset"></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </form>
```

After submitting this form, a coupon gets added and it has to be shown in next table

```
   <br>
   <div id="changecpn">   <!-- DIV with tables, that gets updated by .load() -->
      <h4 class="zusatz">Delete</h4>
      <div class="table-wrapper">
         <table style="width: 100%;" class="fl-table">
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th>Value</th>
                  <th>Delete</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr style="text-align: center;">
                  <td class="items">Coupon1</td>
                  <form action="panelfuncs.php" method="post">   <!-- Form, that has to work before and after refresh -->
                  <input type="hidden" name="delcoup" value="Coupon1">
                  <td><input type="submit" value="Delete"></td>
                  </form>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
</fieldset>
```

I dont know, what the problem is, debugging with console.log() showed, that the formHandler function is not getting called after refresh and submitting, even though before refresh it works fine

Comment: You're attaching submit handlers to your forms on document ready, meaning all forms will get handlers on page load. I suspect that when you refresh, you add a new form (not just update the existing one) and hence lose the attached handler.

Comment: nope, it didn't change anything. The handler is still attached but does not work when submitting the form. Although I found out, that it's working on Microsoft Edge and IE browsers (0_o), but doesnt work on Chrome and FireFox.
[Before](https://prnt.sc/rdqxyf) refreshing,
[After](https://prnt.sc/rdqyj8) refreshing